# How should one maintain serialized objects?

Tags: java, serialization, io, version

I am creating a Serializable object descriptor that will store important state data for a non- Serailizable entity. How do I keep the old descriptors valid across application upgrades? I was thinking of opening all of the known previous state (on upgrade) and prompt the states to upgrade themselves. Maybe via a:

```
void onUpgrade(int oldVersion, int newVersion, int updateFlags);
```

but I don't know if this is a good methodology for serializable maintenance.

Comment: Here's a great article on serialization: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2006/jw-0227-control.html, what you seek would be on page 5 and would involve catching a InvalidClassException and treating the exception. Other approaches would involve using dynamic data and structures with metadata, such as JSONs, XMLs or even descriptor tables in order to keep control of your changes. Hope to have helped.

Comment: @eduardohl That actually helped a lot. Thanks for the link, fairly educational, if one is willing to crawl for a bit.

Comment: There are serious mistakes in that article: for example, the statement about the IllegalArgumentException on field removal is complete fantasy. There is a far better Sun article somewhere which basically says to never change the serialVersionUID and never make an incompatible change.

Comment: I do agree that that solution  proposed by the article is really out of place. I'd go with the accepted solution too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest another form for your external representation. Serialized objects are hard to keep compatible as you already noted. The easiest thing to do would be to annotate your object with jaxb annotations and then use Jaxb to read/write it.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty of object versioning is generally wildly overstated. The great thing is to start out right knowing what you can and cannot do. Have a really good look at the rules in the Object Versioning section of the Object Serialization a specification, and **follow them religiously**:

- don't change the inheritance;
- don't change the datatype of any field;
- restrict yourself to adding and subtracting fields;
- and *never* change the serialVersionUID.

If that doesn't suffice, be prepared to use the writeReplace()/readResolve() mechanism and/or the serializableFields mechanism.

Comment: what is the writeReplace()/readResolve() mechanism? I haven't used it before.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA It is all described in the [Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html), which you should read from cover to cover, excluding the protocol appendix of course. But if you have to go even this far you're doing something wrong, let alone the exception-catching shenanigans described in the JavaWorld article, which would only be attempted by a madman.